# How to monitor the size of Bolt's pending queues?

Tags: apache-storm

My topology has a bottleneck or two. The capacity metric in the Storm UI is useful for identifying these, but I'd be much more interested in the size of Bolt's queues.

My understanding is that each bolt has two queues, one for tuples pending to be executed, and another for tuple pending to be emitted. Is it possible to monitor the size of these queues?

I found some stuff online about adding an ITaskHook implementation to Bolts, but it's not remotely clear how I can use this to monitor queue size. Can the methods in ITaskHook be used for to monitor this?

Comment: As fas as I know, there is no way to get this information...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to see the length of the queues for the components of your topology using the [metrics](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Metrics.html) mechanism. An easy way of doing is to add `conf.registerMetricsConsumer(LoggingMetricsConsumer.class)` to the config of your topology.

Here is an example of what I get for one of my components

`4:fetch        __sendqueue             {write_pos=12122, read_pos=12122, capacity=1024, population=0}
4:fetch         __receive               {write_pos=8588, read_pos=8587, capacity=1024, population=1}`

Comment: Thanks, this looks like exactly what I'm looking for, but I can't find any examples for how to use this. How do I register a Metrics consumer for a bolt? How do I use it to get the output you posted? Particularly, I don't see anything in the metrics storm provides that indicates the _sendqueue and _receive sizes? thanks!

Comment: As shown above you don't register it for a bolt but for the whole topology. The built-in metrics report the queue sizes, you don't need to implement anything specific. The LoggingMetricsConsumer generates a metrics.log file  alongside the worker logs.

Comment: I did the same, but it doesn't seem to work for me. The metrics.log is empty.

Comment: @mini.1601 which version of Storm are you using? Should work fine in the latest, otherwise check the PR I contributed for 0.10 [https://github.com/apache/storm/pull/1222]

Comment: I am using 0.10.0. Is it because I am running my topology in local mode?

Comment: @mini.1601 yes, it will come out on the standard output instead