# Apache Storm: Access Disruptor Queue Size

Tags: apache-storm

I wanted to know how to access the queue size of any executor's incoming queue. I referred to this question:
[How to monitor the size of Bolt's pending queues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162410/how-to-monitor-the-size-of-bolts-pending-queues?rq=1)
But it provides a mechanism to log this information. However, I need to access this data in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. Storm does not provide any API to access this information within the code.

Comment: I guess the same applies to worker level queues as well. In my case, even monitoring as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162410/how-to-monitor-the-size-of-bolts-pending-queues?rq=1 is not working, the metrics.log is always empty.

Comment: Yes. This is internal system information and not exposed.

Comment: Come on, guys, that is not true! All those metrics are easily accessible with a usual simple Java Reflection. We use such Storm Executor monitoring in our project each day (at our DEV/SIT envs). Please refer to the following arcticle with a very detailed description: https://gist.github.com/mrflip/5958028 and https://www.quora.com/How-is-LMAX-being-used-in-Apache-Storm. Also, here is the class that you want to monitor: https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/utils/DisruptorQueue.java